# How do I rotate an image in Adobe Reader for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, pdf, adobe-reader

How do I rotate an image in Adobe Reader in Windows 8? I don't seem to have a "..." or "more" button when I right click. Am I missing something here? Is there a reason it doesn't show up? The only options I have are print, save as, and comments. Other side shows view modes, and find. View modes is just an option of single sheet or continuous. I don't get it?

Comment: Desktop or Windows Store version?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Adobe Reader is really what the name says... a reader. It doesn't allow you to change the document you've opened. You probably need a PDF editor for that.

If what you opened is really an image and not a PDF File then something like the free Image Viewer/Editor IrfanView will do the trick.